# Excel Macro-- How to bifurcate the Json reponse in different columns in excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a JSON response in the below format :

```
{
orders: 
[
5]
0:  
{
orderId: 1
purchaseDate: "2013-08-01"
total: 31
status: "completed"
store: 
{
number: 4
}
-
qty: 3
amount=0
```

Now I want to bifurcate the response with each tag in different columns

```
ordered  purchasedate  total  status store
1        2013-08-01     31    completed 4
```

Is there any macro to convert the JSON response to Excel?

Answer (score 0):

Use Text to Columns, with space as your delimiter. You can choose to omit columns that have stuff you don't need.

Comment: Hi Thank you for the reply, with this option I can split the response in one column into two columns but I need required tags to be displayed as heading in different columns as headings and corresponding values under the headings.